# Next.js authentication pattern/strategy for private pages and a layout

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

Let's say I have 10 pages where 5 are private and 5 are public. In Next.js docs, I've found a slick solution where we add a call to get a user in getServerSideProps, but I also have a layout. In my case it's a header, that I added in _app.js. I want to display the header across all pages. In that header I have an avatar OR a login button. In order to achieve that in the header I added a user call in useEffect in _app. But now I'm going to make a request again when a  user goes on a private page.
In order to get rid of making the same call twice I did:

1. After a call in useEffect in _app.js I store the user state in Redux. (this call we need to decide what to show in the header)
2. I created a PrivateRoute HOC component and add it into pages that should be private.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this approach is good enough doesn't it break something in Next.js? Or it's ok to make two calls for better implementation?
2. Can I verify a user on a server the same as for pages but for a component in _app.js (header in my case)? (adding getInitialProp into _app is not recommend as I understand)

PrivateRoute HOC component

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userSelector } from '../../redux/selectors';

interface IPrivateRoute {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<IPrivateRoute> = (props: IPrivateRoute) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const router = useRouter();
  const user = useSelector(userSelector);

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !user.isUserLoading && user.isAuthenticated === false) {
    router.push('/login');
  }

  if (!user.isUserLoading && user.isAuthenticated === true) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return <></>;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What you're doing is okay and won't break Next. You can make two calls if it's easier or more consistent. If you don't need to you shouldn't, but - it will have minimum impact on a smaller site.
2. Alternatively, you can set your global state for user/roles/is authenticated via server-side response. Then create a hook that reads your global state to get the current user details.  Lastly, you would use the hook throughout your app to make layout changes based on the user details. You use Redux but you could also use React context.

---

At a minimum I would recommend that you always return the corresponding state - as it stands you could return a blank screen. Below is how I would refactor your types and the HOC code so it always returns something.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userSelector } from '../../redux/selectors';

const PrivateRoute: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { push }= useRouter();
  const {isAuthenticated, isUserLoading } = useSelector(userSelector);
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') return null; // wait for mount
  if(isUserLoading) return 'loading screen...'; // mounted & loading
  if(!isAuthenticated) return push('/login'); // mounted & not loading & not authenticated
  return children; // mounted & not loading & authenticated
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

*`children` is included in type `FC` so you don't need to set the children prop*.

Comment: Thanks for your response! React Context can definitely work here, but I get used to Redux, especially with Redux Tool Kit, the amount of code seems to be even less than in React Context. Also I already use it to invoke snackbar etc. After your refactoring it looks more decent but I think I will go with the example from docs which uses `getServerSideProps`. Let it be two calls then, one in _app.js and others on each private page. As you mentioned that's just a small project so I think that's ok. =)